# Как обработать input date в php под один формат?

Tags: javascript, html, дата

В `html input` отображается так `10/19/2021`

В переменной `date` выводит так `2021-10-19`

Подскажите всегда будет такой формат `2021-10-19` если я буду отправлять его по ajax и обрабатывать в php ?

И вне зависимости какая OS у пользователя, какой язык системы, какой браузер и тд ?

И еще реально ли сделать читаемый формат в `html input`, на такой `dd/mm/yyyy` ? (не сильно важно)

```js
$('[name="date"]').on('change', function() {
  let date = $('[name="date"]').val();
  console.log(date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="date">
```

*У меня язык системы английский*

Comment: смените язык на русский и будет `19.10.2021` а не `10/19/2021`

Comment: @teran, понял, отображение не сильно важно, самое главное хочу понять всегда будет в одном формате отправляться в php по ajax в не зависимости какой язык системы, браузера и тд? Чтобы исключить ошибки обработки даты на сервере

Comment: Даты желательно передавать либо как Unix timestamp (числом секунд в UTC), либо ISO-строкой (она тоже всегда в UTC, вида `'2021-10-19T13:28:21.706Z'`) - из этих форматов самый беспроблемный парсинг. Если время в значении зачем-то требуется обнулять, то делать это лучше функциями для работы с датой (до преобразования значения), чтобы исключить ошибки формата из-за кривизны велосипеда.

Comment: @yar85, так это и есть ISO-строка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, какая из дат названа "это"? Я про то что даты желательно как датувремя передавать, в формате который а) содержит время, пусть и нулевое; б) явно предполагает UTC. У автора без времени => есть вероятность наступания на грабли с часовыми поясами при перекодированиях.

Comment: @yar85, `2021-10-19` - соответствует [ISO-8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: @yar85, мне кажется, наоборот наличие времени создаст грабли с часовыми поясами...

Comment: @Qwertiy, напрасно так кажется. А кусочки вида `2021-10-19` хоть и соответствуют ISO-формату в краткой форме, не обязательно будут интерпретированы как даты в UTC автоматически (т.к. не содержат времени с указанием "нулевого" часового пояса).

Comment: @yar85, так они в local, а не в utc.

Comment: @Qwertiy, опять же: кто "они"?

Comment: @yar85, даты вида `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, они не в local, это просто строки без указания таймзоны - поэтому распарсить эти строки можно и как даты в локальном часовом поясе, и как даты в UTC (а так как объекты даты содержат и время, при разном разборе может получиться разница в значении... конечно, если локальный часовой пояс отличается от UTC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата отправляется в ISO-формате, который не зависит от локали пользователя. Тем не менее, я бы всё же проверил одинаковость формата в разных браузерах.

А вот отображается наоборот в соответствии с настройками текущей локали, так что не надо трогать отображение.